# list of files deleted from SVN working copy

Tags: svn

I checked out an svn repository made some changes. These changes involved deleting some files. Is there a way to find the list of deleted files from SVN working folder so that I can remove those from the repository

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly the `svn status | sed  -n '/!/ s,^! *,,p'` is the solution.
Check [svn status](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html):

> The first column indicates that an item was added, deleted, or
>   otherwise changed:
>
> '!':
>   Item is missing (e.g., you moved or deleted it without using svn).

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted the file using `svn delete (del, remove, rm)`, it will remove files from version control and just do svn status it will show

`'D'` : it means items are schedule for deletion.

---

If you didn't use svn rm then you will see this `!`

`'!'`: Item is missing (e.g. you moved or deleted it without using svn). This also indicates that a directory is incomplete (a checkout or update was interrupted).

If you have so many files modified and you can filter out using shell commands such as `grep`or `find` or `cut` or `sed` or `awk`.